# Need to "link" table cell editor with its table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, tablecelleditor

I need to customise the selection behaviour of the cells inside a `JTable` descendant.  I have a custom cell editor using a `JTextField` descendant as the `editorComponent`; there's a focus listener registered on it which manages the desired selection behaviour.

I need different behaviour when tabbing around the table than when another window or application comes to the front and then goes away again.

This is currently not possible, because the cell editor's `editorComponent` seems to have no off-the-shelf way of knowing (or telling it) that it's the editor for a table cell, so it doesn't know that it's "inside" the table, so my `focusGained()` and `focusLost()` think focus is moving between different windows even if I'm just tabbing around in the table.

`SwingUtilities.windowForComponent()` returns `null` for the `editorComponent`.

Before I roll my own solution, is there an accepted way of dealing with this issue?  I can't be the first person to need to do this...

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Your `TableCellEditor` knows on which table cell it is operating by means of the `table`, `row` and `column` arguments it got in the [`getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html#getTableCellEditorComponent-javax.swing.JTable-java.lang.Object-boolean-int-int-) method call.

Comment: Sure, but I don't get that info inside `focusGained()` and `focusLost()`, which is where I need to manage the text selectedness.  There's no useful information at all in there.

Comment: Whatever, I've ended up rolling my own.  I would have preferred to use support from within swing, but my focus listener now knows which table the JTextField is editing within.